# How to use list/array of some object inheritance with Protobuf/Protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Using Protobuf/Protobuf-net and two classes, one base class and the other derived from the base.
How would you serialize/deserialize a list ?

For instance:

```
public class SomeBase
{
    ...
}

public class SomeDerived : SomeBase
{
    ...
}
```

And the following field to be serialized:

```
public List<SomeBase> SomeList;
```

Keep in mind that the list contains SomeBase and SomeDerived objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work, you simply need to assign a tag (number) that it will use to identify the sub-type. Basically, the core "protocol buffers" wire spec doesn't handle inheritance, so protobuf-net achieves it by modelling inheritance as encapsulation. You assign tags on properties/fields with `[ProtoMember]`, and sub-types via `[ProtoInclude]` (compare to `[XmlInclude]`).

Note that the tags must be unique within any *single* type, but that they can be re-used in sub-types - as shown in the example by both levels using tag 1.

Like so:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProtoBuf;

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(20, typeof(SomeDerived))]
public class SomeBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string BaseProp { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeDerived : SomeBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int DerivedProp { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeEntity
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<SomeBase> SomeList;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SomeEntity orig = new SomeEntity
        {
            SomeList = new List<SomeBase> {
                new SomeBase { BaseProp = "abc"},
                new SomeDerived { BaseProp = "def", DerivedProp = 123}
            }
        };
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(orig);
        // clone now has a list with 2 items, one each SomeBase and SomeDerived
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: Will somebody on other end of wire be able to handle this in Java/C++? and second question: Is this doable with .proto?(if both yes can you please give .proto sample? ty

Comment: @David protobuf-net implements inheritance via encapsulation, so SomeBase will have an optional field of type SomeDerived, with field number 20. GetProto/GetSchema will illustrate this. However, protobuf-net does not *generate* inheritance in the codegen layer (if starting from .proto), because .proto has no metaphor to describe such.